# How can I deactivate left tray icons?

Tags: kubuntu

I use Kubuntu, and I have installed Plank Dock. When I open anything in Plank, the same will be open at left up tray. How can I deactivate those?

[image: desktop screenshot]

Comment: You mean the "taskbar" icons in the top left of the panel ? I havn't used KDE in a while but you should be able to click on the three horizontal lines in the very top right, and that will allow you to edit the contents and layout / widgets of the panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's the "windows" that are running in the taskbar you want to remove so it doesn't show them you can do the following:

1. `Right click on the taskbar` and choose `Unlock Widgets`
2. `Click the "3 line" icon` at the far right of the "taskbar" panel
3. `Hover over the center of the "taskbar"` and you should see a popup saying `"Task Manager"`
4. There should be a little `"X"` there to close that widget. Click the `"X"`.

That should do it .. but ... it may move your clock and system tray over to the left side so you can (while the panel is still unlocked) just drag them back to the right

Once you have the panel set up the way you want you can then click the `"X"` on the popup that came up when you clicked the `"3 line icon"` Then you can right click on the panel again and go to `Panel Options` and `Lock Widgets` again

That should remove the programs from showing up in the upper panel

Comment: Done! Thank you very much for your solution @John Orion and thank you very much Zanna for correct my mistakes, my english isn't very well. (SOLVED)

Comment: since this worked for you .. you can help me out by accepting this as the answer :D ... glad it worked out for you :D

Comment: How can I do it? : "accepting this as the answer"

Comment: I think you have a 'grey checkmark' near the upper left at the start of the question .. I think you click that and it will mark the answer as being accepted. .... lol .. it just gives me a bit of reputation .. if you cant figure it out .. don't worry about it .. glad to help